# What is wrong with this C++ multi-threaded program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I write a multi-threaded C++ program using `std::thread` that looks like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

const int threadNum = 4;
mutex mt[threadNum];
condition_variable cv[threadNum];
thread threadList[threadNum];
bool threadWork[threadNum];

void work(int id) {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mt[id]);
        cv[id].wait(lck, [&]() { return threadWork[id]; }); // wait for incoming tasks
        
        // do something
        
        threadWork[id] = false;
        cv[id].notify_all();
    }
}
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i ++) {
        threadWork[i] = false;
        threadList[i] = thread(work, i);
    }

    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i ++) {
            // allocate tasks for each threads
            threadWork[i] = true;
            cv[i].notify_all();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i ++) {
            // wait until all tasks finish
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(mt[i]);
            cv[i].wait(lck, [&]() { return !threadWork[i]; });
            cout << "Finish thread " << i << endl;
        }

        // do something
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i ++)
        threadList[i].join();
    return 0;
}
```

In iterations of the program, the main thread and sub threads will execute alternatively. The main thread will first allocate tasks for multiple sub threads. After all threads finish their tasks, the main thread will aggregate the information and do some other computation.

However, during execution, the program will crash or get stuck in dead locks after a few iterations randomly. I have no idea why this happens. What the problem with it?

My environment: ubuntu 22.04, g++ 11.4

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to figure the problem out?

Comment: Try compiling and running it with `thread sanitizer`, `address sanitizer` and `undefined behaviour sanitizer` and also use your [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: @Quimby -- a debugger usually isn't a good tool for debugging multi-threaded programs. The issues often arise from the timing of events in different threads, which isn't something you can observe or control with a debugger.

Comment: Looks like main sets       threadWork[i] = true; without any synchronization, which introduces a race condition and so invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Quimby I do try to debug, but I am not sure how to use gdb to debug multi-threaded programs ...

Comment: @PeteBecker "The issues often arise from the timing of events in different threads, which isn't something you can observe or control with a debugger" - that's where debuggers like [rr](https://rr-project.org/) enter the picture, where you can step backwards in time as well as replay a specific program run multiple times with deterministic behaviour. It's quite useful 

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- interesting, but I'm skeptical. Especially because "emulates a single-core machine. So, parallel programs incur the slowdown of running on a single core" -- it's not just a slowdown, it's a different environment; in particular, only one cache, while a multi-core system has multiple caches. But I haven't used it, so my reaction really isn't worth much. Nevertheless, "Have you tried using a debugger" is vastly different from "Have you tried this fancy debugger that can do things that an ordinary debugger can't?"

Comment: One thing I'm missing in your code is a comment that says which data is shared and which mutex is used to protect that shared data. For bonus points, put all related objects (mutex, data and CV) into a `struct`, which serves as implicit documentation. Doing so, it could perhaps become clear that you are accessing some shared data without mutex protection. BTW: There's no need for globals. Pass a pointer or reference around instead of an index into some global array.

Comment: As already noted, there's a data race on `threadWork[i]`; `main` sets it without synchronization. I don't see how this could lead to a crash, but I do see how it could lead to a worker thread missing the signal and getting stuck in `wait` forever.

Answer (score 0):

Coments in code below:

```
//...
mutex mt[threadNum];           // Mutexes are for synchronizing 
                               // between threads.  Having 1 mutex
                               // per thread is not proper the way
                               // to guard access to data.
                               // try having 1 mutex per block of 
                               // data that you want guarded instead.

condition_variable cv[threadNum];  // same applies for the condition variables
                                   // you want to indicate that the DATA 
                                   // is ready.
// ... 
// The rest of the code will need a bit of reordering.
```

You should try, for your experiment something a bit easier, let's say, with only one block of guarded data, to start with.  Here's an example below.

Note in the code below that the worker threads wait for the one unique condition variable telling them that something needs done.

I've also added a simple mechanism to exit gracefully from the program once the work is done.  That's as important as the rest, note the use of atomic<>, which guarantees that all cores will see the change in value as soon as it's made.

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>

std::mutex my_data_mutex;
std::condition_variable my_data_cv;
std::vector<int> my_data;
constexpr size_t threadNum = 4;
std::atomic<bool> halt = false;


void work(int id) {
    for(;;)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _(my_data_mutex);
        my_data_cv.wait(_);  // wait for incoming tasks

        if (halt)
            return;
        // do something
        my_data.push_back(my_data.back() + id);
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::thread> tasks;
    for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++) {
        tasks.emplace_back(work, i);
    }

    while(!halt)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _(my_data_mutex);

        my_data.push_back(0);             // do some silly job
                                          // note tht the worker threads
                                          // would seg fault when 
                                          // the array is empty (try it!)
                                          // thank god, they're waiting, for now.

        if (my_data.size() > 1'000'000)   // exit when job is done.
            halt = true;                  // tell all that the jobn is done

        my_data_cv.notify_all();          // tell all threads to do their silly part
    }

    for (auto& t : tasks)
        t.join();

   return 0;
}
```